# How to querying across databases with grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, orm

Is there a way to querying across 2 databases in grails ?

Example (I made a select on two databases - works and test) :

```
        select
            c.crf_name,
            c.crf_id,
            ig.group_id,
            ig.group_name,
        from
            works.crfs c,
            test.item_groups ig;
```

1) I would like to query against two databases, and attach results to a domain.

Or :

2) Is it possible to mixing one query part with data from database and other part with domain class ?

**Edit** : I need to do a single query mixing tables from 2 databases (one db is PostgreSQL and other db is Mysql). So, in grails is it possible to mix to dataSources beans in one query ?

**Edit 2 : Here a better example :**

```
select
    igm.item_id,
    igm.item_group_id as group_id,
    igm.crf_version_id,
    ig.name as group_name
from
    works.item_group_metadata igm,
    test.item_group ig
where
    igm.item_group_id=ig.item_group_id
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning [to do your own sql](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL) (like it seems to be the case) over 2 datasources, I suggest that you define your 2 datasources as Spring beans in grails-app/conf/spring.

e.g. (drop your db drivers in /lib and replace the values to match your RDBMS drivers and connection string) :

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

beans = { 
    worksDataSource(BasicDataSource) {
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:someport:works"
        username = "works"
        password = "workspassword"
     }

     testDataSource(BasicDataSource) {
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@someserver:someport:test"
        username = "test"
        password = "testpassword"
     }
}
```

Then create a service to handle your queries, like :

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class SomeService {
    def worksDataSource
    def testDataSource

    def query1 = """
          SELECT crf_name, crf_id
            FROM works.crfs
    """

    def query2 = """
          SELECT group_id, group_name
            FROM test.item_groups
    """

    def sqlWorks = Sql.newInstance(query1)
    def sqlTest = Sql.newInstance(query2)

    // Then do whatever you like with the results of the 2 queries
    // e.g. 

    sqlWorks.eachRow{ row -> 
       def someDomainObject = new SomeDomainObject(prop1 : row.crf_name, prop2 : crf_id)
       someDomainObject.otherProp = whateverYouLike()
       someDomainObject.save()
    }    
}
```

Your query doesn't have a where clause so I don't know how you want to relate the data coming from your 2 tables...

If you want to do a single query mixing tables from 2 databases, (ask your DBA to) establish a DBLink between databases test and works and perform the query on the datasource containing the DBLink.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I want to do a single query mixing tables from 2 databases. I would like to mix sqlWorks and sqlTest in one query. I suppose, it's not possible to add sqlTest in my sqlWorks closure? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, but I think there is a problem in the query you posted : I can't see how you join your 2 tables without a where clause...
Also, what RDBMSs are you using for your 2 databases ? Are you doing all by yourself or working with a DBA ?

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL and Mysql. And I'm doing all by myself.
You right, my query was not good for this example, I will edit a new query. If it possible can you show me an example in grails with my new query ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "UNION SELECT" which is supported by most databases. Make sure that both select statements have the same number of columns.

```
    select
        crf_name,
        crf_id
    from
        ig
    UNION SELECT
        group_id,
        group_name
    from
        id
```

A union select concatenates the results for 2 queries, for example:

```
select 1 union select 2
```

Comment: Can you show me an example ? How to use UNION with sqlconnector.eachRow('''select...''')? Where I define my two dataSource with grails ?

Comment: Idk man,  if you can't get a row,  then you should take a few steps back and start with the very basics of sql.

Comment: My problem is more complex, because I need to do a single query mixing tables from 2 databases (one db is PostgreSQL and other db is Mysql). I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Datasources plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources)? It sounds like it will do what you require, but I think you'd need to use HQL or finders on the domain objects directly, rather than SQL, for it to work.

I haven't used the plugin myself but I'd be interested to hear how it goes it you try it.

HTH

Comment: This plugin seems very interesting, I'll try test app example... Thanks.